# Prevent Scrollable Widget scroll out of top in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Sorry because I don't know how to explain this behavior exactly in English. So I give a gif image for easy understanding.

I want to avoid/ prevent seeing white background when scrolling over the top of SingleChildScrollView.

These are my code for this behavior:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        height: LayoutUtils.getScreenHeight(context) + 1000, // Just get screen height and plus 1000 units
      )),
    );
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? And please correct my question to make sense. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: How about making your `Scaffold` background color to the same `Colors.amberAccent`?

Comment: hmmmm try physic alwaysScrollablePhysics or NestScrollablePhysic to avoid a scrolling like bouncing

Comment: I use ```physics : ClampingScrollPhysics()``` as @Kaushik Chandru suggest and it work like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the SingleChildScrollView add

```
physics : ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

For more info about scrollphysics check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html)